# How to split this range of negative numbers

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have this "-6--15" and I want to split this into -6 and -15.

Here is my code in C#:

```
string[] groups = Regex.Split("-6--15",@"\d+\-{1}");
```

But it returns - and -15.

Help!

Comment: will the format will remain the same every time or will change?

Comment: what code is producing the range? can you change the delimiter to something else like a pipe symbol?

Comment: the numbers might be positive or negative. cant change the delimiter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following:

```
string[] groups = Regex.Split("-6--15", @"(?<=\d)-");
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=\d)-
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sP3gL7)**

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about this kind of regex! Learning.

Comment: however i just noticed this will only work for one-digit numbers, any way to make it support any number size

Comment: @user1109363 Can you provide the sample where it doesn't work?

Comment: @user1109363 Works for me. Returns 2-item array `{-12; -5}`.

Comment: Yeah, a RegEx is appropriate here. I missed OP's comment about the possibility of positive numbers in my answer. If you take that into account, the "regular code" gets more complicated. Personally I try to avoid RegExs whenever I can, because I find they are often difficult to understand without explanatory comments.

Comment: More power to the mighty lookbehind... +1 :)